# Mac OS Static vs Dynamic Linking having same size of executable

Tags: macos, compilation, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

There is a c++ library, against which I tried linking both statically and dynamically. 
I generated the .so file and installed at a path, properly setting the install_name, LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

But the problem is, I am not seeing any difference in the size of executable produced in both cases

My Makefile is as follows:

```
# dynamic linking
alld:
    g++ -std=c++11 -O3  main.cpp -o main -lpthread -lm -ldlib
alls:
# static linking
    g++ -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp -o main /Users/prakhar/bin/lib/static/dlib.a -lpthread -lm
```

In both cases I am getting same size of executable.

When I statically link and remove the library, it still runs. So it is indeed statically linked.
But when I dynamically link, and remove shared library, it does not run at all.

Why this is happening?

I am using MacOS Catalina.

Comment: You might want to run `otool -L` on the resulting binary to see what is dynamically linked.

Comment: I had done already. It was indeed the libdlib.a. Also, the experiment where I removed the library and it stopped running is also an indication.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is happening?

Do you actually *use* the `dlib` library in your `main.cpp` ?

If you don't, the observed behavior is easy to explain: with either static or dynamic linking, the library is not used, and so no part of it is getting linked into the binary in static link case. In the dynamic linking case, the linker records that this library is needed at runtime, so removing it (naturally) prevents the executable from starting.

Comment: Yes, I am using some matrix inverse functions. I wonder if it is possible that dlib is doing all of them inline?